# Reactive api calls in meteor

Tags: http, meteor

The situation is like the following:

- We have another backend server and the meteor server can only talk to it
- our server is a little smart, so when you call for example `/employees` on it, it will send all the `employees` plus it will observe the collection if its updates it will send meteor server a ping request telling it that `employee` collection has been updated via another http request. it will be like the following

---

```
* user go to employees screen

/employees
meteor --(http)-> api 

* admin adds a new employee

/ping
meteor <-(http)-- api

/employees
meteor --(http)-> api
```

What I wanna do it the following:

- I want meteor to be reactive, best case scenario I don't want the client to know all the details, want it to just subscribe to the server
- want all the plumbing work to be on the meteor server, I want to somehow publish the api when the clients go to a certain page (we are using iron router) and then whenever the backend server updates want the server refetches it and send it back to the client

---

I am a little lost, I'm kinda new to meteor and read about `reactive-var`, `tracking`, `local-collections`, but Just can't think of a way to implement this solution, if anyone could solve the issue or point me to the right direction it would be great

Comment: You have 2 separate servers. One meteor server the users connect to and one that ONLY meteor can connect to? I'm guessing this other server was already in place and you're wanting to use meteor to get reactivity from it?

Comment: yes, that was part of the app infrastructure we don't have control over it

Comment: Is creating a "copy" of the employee results into a meteor collection out of the question? Seems to me the most simple solution. Meteor gets the employee list from server2, puts them into a collection that clients can subscribe to. Whenever server2 pings Meteor, it will add the changes to it's collection. When the collection is updated it sends the updates to the client automagically.

Comment: no that won't work, because the data coming down is more complicated (consists of multiple entities) so the approach for replicating the data to meteor mongo will create a lot of headache + duplicate + possible data inconsistency

Comment: It seems like you're basically building a reactive cache. Your last comment "whenever the backend server updates want the server refetches it and send it back to the client" - that means the Meteor server is publishing data and the way it does that is either as collections or arrays. An intermediate approach might be to simply cache the ids of the primary db objects (and any fields needed for filtering) and then that collection would be reactive without completely mirroring the original data. When you load a detailed view you could go fetch the whole complex object.